# VB.NET WPF - Populate Combobox with values from a JSON array

Tags: json, vb.net, combobox

I have a json array like the following in a local file (local.json)

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Element1",
    "Url": "https://someurlforelement1.com"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Element1",
    "Url": "https://someurlforelement2.com"
  }
]
```

The corresponding class in vb

```
Public Class MyElement
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Url As String
End Class
```

I am trying to read the json file at the start of the application and populate a combobox with the list of MyElement objects.
The goal is to display the Name property but use as value the Url property of the objects.
I've tried a couple of things after googling but I'm fairly new to VB.NET and having to pick up other devs work so in need of help :) Thanks

EDIT: This is the final code starting from an answer provided below:

```
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    ' Read json and setup the combobox
    Dim rawjson = File.ReadAllText(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\local.json")
    Dim lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of MyElement))(rawjson)
    For Each i In lst
        filterComboBox.Items.Add(i)
    Next
    filterComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name"
    filterComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "Url"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using this you can get list of your class objects
but for that you need to import Newtonsoft.Json

```
 Dim rawjson = File.ReadAllText(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\local.json")

            Dim lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of MyElement))(rawjson)
```

Now create loop using this list and fill your combobox

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to work it out starting from this! Added the final code in the question

Comment: @Mik1893 Please accept answer ..It will help me little bit... :-)